# addEventListener working in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser

The given code works in Mozilla Firefox 31.0 but not in Google Chrome 38.0.2125.104
How can this issue be solved?

Please Note : Using the change() function or jQuery is not an option here!

```
<body>
    <select id="category">
        <option value="movies">Movies</option>
        <option value="artist">Artists</option>
        <option value="authors">Authors</option>
        <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
    </select>
</body>

<script>
window.onload = initialise;
function initialise() {
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].addEventListener("click", getQuestion, false);
        //console.log(i);
    }
}

function getQuestion() {
    console.log("getting question..");
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Not all browsers dispatch click events on option elements since they can be selected using other means. If you want an event when an option is selected, use the change event of the parent select.

Comment: Notice you made an edit to say that using change is not an option any reason why?

Comment: Change is not an option because in you may need to select the same option again.

Comment: How do you indicate the selection of the same option again without first selecting some other option? Perhaps you need a form.

Comment: Maybe you should not use a select control and just style a dropdown list in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why they all aren't binding but aren't you look for the on change function? So you can just bind to that once?

```
//Untested
var Category = document.getElementsById('category');
Category.addEventListener("change", getQuestion, false);
```

Also, If you're not against Jquery, you might want to look into it it often gets rid of cross-browser issues.  In Jquery:

```
 $('body').on('change', '#category', function() {
     getQuestion($(this));
 })
```

Comment: That works not because of any special jQuery magic, but because you're using a more appropriate event. Note that this too works differently in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = initialise();

    function getQuestion() {
        console.log("getting question..");
    }

    function initialise() {
        var Category = document.getElementById('category');
        Category.addEventListener("change", getQuestion, false);
    }

</script>
```